# Inclusion of HTML into another page on the same site?

Tags: html, dependency-injection

I have an HTML webpage with a specialized purpose.  However, I also have a HTML page with a generic set of actions used elsewhere in my site/app.

**Specific Page**

```
<html>
  <head><title>Specific Page</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Specific Action</h1>

    <div id="NameAction">
      <!-- Action HTML goes here... -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Generic Action**

```
<html>
  <body>
    Please tell me your name...
    <input id="NameText" type="text" size="50" />
    <input id="NameSubmit" type="submit" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The question is, I would like to inject the Generic Action HTML into the NameAction div in the Specific Page.  What are some ways I would go about doing this?

Comment: iFrames or includes would be the most typical.

Comment: iFrames are not the way the project I am working on wants to go; how do you accomplish these includes?

Comment: @AndrewGray would SSI (server side includes) work, for example `<?php include("myfile.html"); ?>`?

Comment: Yes go the SSI route.  Have a file without the HTML/BODY tags that you include from various places.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Actually, yes, though not with PHP; we're using MVC 3 and jQuery.

Comment: SSI is exactly what I suggested in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe

```
<html>
  <head><title>Specific Page</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Specific Action</h1>

    <div id="NameAction">
      <iframe src="Path-to-generic-html" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I frames should be a last resort. They are a very undesirable solution when you're talking about content that is hosted on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe, which is a way to embed one html document into another, however this makes it difficult for the two html fragments to interact on the front end (Javascript, etc.). Depending on what templating engine you're using (jsp, php, asp) you should be able to include html fragment into a page as follows (server side include):

**Generic Action Fragment**

```
Please tell me your name...
<input id="NameText" type="text" size="50" />
<input id="NameSubmit" type="submit" />
```

**Specific Page**

```
<html>
  <head><title>Specific Page</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Specific Action</h1>

    <div id="NameAction">
      <% include generic action fragment here using engine specific code %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would be a better way that would take advantage of JavaScript?  Is there some kind of jQuery system that would provide this sort of functionality?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you're just trying to put those two input tags in various places, the best way to do it would be on the back end before the page is rendered. You could do it via jQuery (make an ajax call that returns the html fragment and then update the dom), but it seems overly complex for what you're trying to do.